# Optimising a function to convert a (directed) edge list to an adjacency list

Tags: python, numpy, graph-theory

I have written a function which converts a list of 2-tuples (representing the edges of a directed graph) into an array of lists (representing which vertices you can get to if you start at the vertex given by the array index).

What I have so far:

```py
def make_graph(edges, amount_of_vertices):
    graph = [[] for _ in range(amount_of_vertices)]

    for edge in edges:
        graph[edge[0]].append(edge[1])

    return graph
```

So, for this graph:

[image: a graph with edges 0→1, 2→0, 1→2 and 0→2]

It would do this:

```
>>> make_graph([(0, 1), (2, 0), (1, 2), (0, 2)], 3)
[[1, 2], [2], [0]]
```

From vertex 0, you can get to vertices 1 and 2, etc..

It works fine and gives the output I want, but for my application this *isn't fast enough* – my *real* graphs will have about 100 000 to 1 000 000 vertices with 1–4 million edges. Is there a way to increase the performance? Perhaps another list comprehension, or `numpy`?

I am open to solutions to this in other languages, if Python can't do it any faster.

Comment: Don't ask us: ask Python.  What happened when you coded each of your suggestions?

Comment: I mean it works fine, Python doesn't spit out an Exception and that's also not my problem. I'm asking how to improve its efficiency in terms of time spent creating the graph. Can I somehow ask Python how to make it faster or am I missing something?

Comment: how many vertices is your graph, can you hold a nxn numpy array in your memory?

Comment: It's around the range of 100'000 to 1'000'000 nodes with a 1-4 million connections.

Comment: I know that your posted code works fine; how about your comprehension code and your NumPy code?

Comment: Have you checked Python's [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) module?

Comment: I actually haven't fiddled around with that, because I'm not all too knowledgeable in the inner workings of python and what's the fastest. I can try something and edit in later, although it would probably less efficient.

Comment: Actually mathux answer below has a link to performance for different packages. From his benchmarks, [networkit](https://networkit.github.io/) is a lot faster than networkx.

Comment: @LuM I've had a go at editing your question to make it clearer. Feel free to revert my edit or make further amendments if it isn't to your liking, or misrepresents the problem you have, or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most popular ways is to do it with `networkx` package. Actually, it is quite slow despite its quite friendly design. Fortunately, it has some alternatives for Python. This is [detailed analysis of performace](https://www.timlrx.com/2019/05/05/benchmark-of-popular-graph-network-packages/). I've tested alternatives such as `igraph` and `graph-tools`. However, graph-tools has a pretty good documentation but is Linux based and since I'm a Windows user, it was not accessible for me. Finally `igraph` did work for me after installing it from [unoficial binaries](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and I'm pretty satisfied with performance. Hovewer, `igraph` accepts nodes that are labeled as integers starting from 0, therefore you will need to create remapping of nodes if needed.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out!

Comment: Also, keep in mind that networkx is documented very well and documentation of igraph is quite poor.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by removing the dict-related overhead with a defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict

connenctions = defaultdict(list)
connection_input = [(0, 1), (2, 0), (1, 2), (0, 2)]

for x, y in connection_input:
    connenctions[x].append(y)


>>> connenctions.values()

dict_values([[1, 2], [0], [2]])
```

Comment: I have implemented your proposed solution as a function, but it actually seems to be about 1/5 slower than my original function.

Comment: Using `defaultdicts` should be just a little speed up. Despite this, looping can't be avoided here. Python loops are quite huge performance consumer as to compare with C still. However, the waste is relatively small as to compare with graph operations performed on graph libraries.

Comment: @LuM, are you sure you're timing the correct part? The point is to remove the part of your code here: `graph = [[] for _ in range(amount_of_vertices)]`. When timing the relevant parts, I'm getting back that my script takes 512 ns and yours takes 1.26 µs. I'm almost sure it wouldn't be slower.

Comment: @mathfux, agreed. I was actually going to post something similar to networkx but wasn't sure if it'd be too much overhead for OP. And yeah something faster like a list comp isn't an option in this case since we're doing case-specific list appending and appending in a list comp is a no-no